# How to access data via dot-notation

Tags: python, oop, syntax, pyramid

Goal: Pull `video_id` from `assessment_obj`, assign to variable
DB Type: SQLAlchemy 
Model: `Assessment` holds `video_id` in a Many-to-One relationship (multiple assessments can use a video)

1.) I am trying to use `dot.notation` to pull the `video_id` from the assessment  2.) so that I can use the `retrieve` method to pull the video information (such as `url`).

Purpose: The video `url` will be used to enter into a video player `src` via a `JINJA2` template/`HTML` code. *(I apologize if I am using jargon incorrectly as I am new and am trying to better understand the concepts.)*

I was trying to follow a `OOP` `dot.notation` [tutorial](http://reeborg.ca/docs/oop_py_en/oop.html#for-the-advanced-reader), but was uncertain on how to pull the data from a table and assign to a variable without accidently reassigning the variable.

**views.py** 
The form view config.

```
@view_config(route_name='save_assessment_result', renderer='templates/completedpage.jinja2')
def save_assessment_result(request):
    with transaction.manager:
        assessment_id = int(request.params['assessment_id'])
        assessment_obj = api.retrieve_assessment(assessment_id) # the assessment

        assessment_obj.video_id = video # this right? 
        thevid = api.retrieve_video(video) #retrieves the video via ID
        template_video = int(request.params['video'])
        # how do I get the retrieved video 'thevid' into the template? 

        # more code 

       transaction.commit()
       return HTTPCreated()
```

**template:** `templates/assessment_form.jinja2`

```
  <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe width="640" height="360" class="embed-responsive-item" allowfullscreen name='video' src="{{ url }}"></iframe>
  </div>
```

NEW: Return for `assessment_obj`. New View_Config.
*Note:* `'videoname': video.videoname, 'length': video.length, 'url': video.url`

```
@view_config(route_name='assessment', request_method='GET', renderer='templates/assessment_form.jinja2')
def assessment_form_view(request):
    with transaction.manager:
        assessment_id = int(request.matchdict['id'])
        assessment = api.retrieve_assessment(assessment_id)
        if not assessment:
            raise HTTPNotFound()
        video_id = int(request.matchdict['id']) # <--- this gives the assessmnet_id and not the video
        video = api.retrieve_video(video_id)
        return {'assessment_id': assessment_id, 'assessment_name': assessment.name, 'assessment_text': assessment.text, 'user_id': assessment.user_id, 'video_id':assessment.video_id, 'categories': ','.join([str(i) for i in assessment.categories]), 'video_id':video_id, 'videoname': video.videoname, 'length': video.length, 'url': video.url}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line `assessment_obj.video_id = video` - where does the `video` variable come from?

Seeing that you're trying "pull the data from a table and assign to a variable" I'm wondering if you actually tried to assign `assessment_obj.video_id` to a variable called `video`. In this case it should be another way round:

```
video = assessment_obj.video_id
```

Then you code almost starts to make sense. To pass the data to the template you simply return a dictionary from your view function:

```
@view_config(route_name='save_assessment_result', renderer='templates/assessment_form.jinja2')
def save_assessment_result(request):
    with transaction.manager:
        assessment_id = int(request.params['assessment_id'])
        assessment_obj = api.retrieve_assessment(assessment_id) # the assessment

        video_id = assessment_obj.video_id
        thevid = api.retrieve_video(video_id)
        template_video = int(request.params['video'])
        return {
           'thevid': thevid,
           'template_video': template_video
        }
```

Then in your template you can reference those variables and their members:

```
<iframe ... src="{{ thevid.url }}"></iframe>
```

Comment: This is fantastic... and thank you for catching my reversal of the variable. Yikes. I notice this suggestion still does not pull up the video. No traceback either or error. I added the attributes that are available via `assessment_obj` above.

Comment: `{{ thevid.url }}` needs to be `{{url}}`  ... so add to the return values..e.g. `'url': thevid.url,`  but still doesn't work for some reason

Comment: @thesayhey: I don't see you returning the dictionary from the function - instead, you're returning `HTTPCreated()`, which is a custom Response object. If you're returning a Response your template is not used at all. You need to return the dictionary for the template to be invoked.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion... I am using your exact code except I added the `'url': thevid.url`  to the return value

Comment: I added the template name and assessment ... for a better picture of what is happening.

Comment: @thesayhey: in `def get_assessment()` you also need to retrieve the video using `thevid = api.retrieve_video(assesment.video_id)` and then return the video's url in the dictionary. Currently you're retrieveing it in `save_assessment_result` and I don't think it's actually used for anything

Comment: Got it working ! Thank you for your clean and clear suggestions. `assessment_form_view` is now pulling the video_id and retrieving it...The key was to stop looking at `save_assessment_result` as the source for pulling the video up...that was for saving `POST` the results from the template form. Thank you Sergey!

Answer (score 0):

Per Sergey's amazing guidance I created a new view configuration that loaded the assessment and the video. I then returned the values needed.

Working code:

```
@view_config(route_name='assessment', request_method='GET', renderer='templates/assessment_form.jinja2')
def assessment_form_view(request):
    with transaction.manager:
        assessment_id = int(request.matchdict['id'])
        assessment = api.retrieve_assessment(assessment_id)
        if not assessment:
            raise HTTPNotFound()

        video = assessment.video_id
        print 'test_video_id', video
        video_obj = api.retrieve_video(video)
        print 'test_video_obj', video_obj

        return {'assessment_id': assessment_id, 'assessment_name': assessment.name, 'assessment_text': assessment.text, 'user_id': assessment.user_id, 'categories': ','.join([str(i) for i in assessment.categories]), 'url': video_obj.url, 'video_id':video_obj.video_id, 'videoname': video_obj.videoname, 'length': video_obj.length}
```